# Error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /SearchGenre.jsp(1,20) quote symbol expected" in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I try to connect to hyperion database on via jboss and run sql statement.
I have the followin jsp file:

```
<%@ page import = java.sql.* %>
<%@ page import = java.* %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 IntialContext ic = new InitialContext();
 DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/DefaultDS");
 Connection con = ds.getConnection();

 PreparedStatement prSelect = 
 con.prepareStatement("select * from public.users where user = ?");

 prSelect.getString(1,genre);

 ResultSet rs = prSelect.executeQuery();

 while (rs.next()) {
   system.out.println("FOUND!!!!!");
}
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error message

> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /SearchGenre.jsp(1,20) quote symbol
>   expected
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:200)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:150)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.getPageEncodingForJspSyntax(ParserController.java:451)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:392)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:173)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:167)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA logs.

what is my problem?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `<% %>` symbols to wrap your code and make it scriptlet. If you don't, then use a `try/catch` block to wrap it and provide the exact stacktrace of your problem.

Comment: java codes directly inside html body?

Comment: You could do better by decoupling the presentation layer and the business layer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some quote symbols. For example:

```
<%@ page import = java.sql.* %>
<%@ page import = java.* %>
```

This should be:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.*" %>
```

Note that your problem has nothing to do with JDBC (which BTW you would ideally not handle inside the JSP).

Also your last import is irrelevant: there is nothing in the package `java`. Unless you put your own classes in that package, which is contrary to the guideline for package names.

And finally: your current JSP page will **display** your code, it will not execute it.

To avoid all these problems, it would be better to not have any scriptlet **at all**. More info: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)